# Object not generating Dynamic Proxy

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have a project where some of my objects are generating DyanmicProxy classes and their changes are being tracked and some objects that are not.

Example: Category Security - This is not generating a dynamic proxy.
(I had screenshots but it would let me post it)

```
tempObject {Workflow.Data.Access.CategorySecurity} - no Dynamic Proxy appended.
```

Example 2: MenuItem - This is generating a dynamic proxy.

```
tempObject {System.Data.Entity.DyanmicProxies.MenuItem_782678127361273612738818AEDD878723827}
```

MENU ITEM - which works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Workflow.Data.Communication;

namespace Workflow.Data.Access
{

[Table("MenuItem", Schema = "wfa")]
public class MenuItem
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; internal set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Display Name")]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Visible")]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Order")]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("URL")]
    public string URL { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Browser Target")]
    public string BrowserTarget { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Menu")]
    [InverseProperty("MenuItems")]
    [UIHint("WorkflowMenu")]
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Parent Item")]
    [InverseProperty("ChildMenuItems")]
    public virtual MenuItem ParentMenuItem { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Menu Items")]
    [InverseProperty("ParentMenuItem")]
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> ChildMenuItems { get; internal set; }

    [DisplayName("Responsibilites View Access")]
    [InverseProperty("MenuItems")]
    public virtual ICollection<Responsibility> ViewAccess { get; internal set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Update Date")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int LastUpdateUserID { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Last Update Date")]
    [ForeignKey("LastUpdateUserID")]
    public virtual WorkflowUser LastUpdateUser { get; set; }

    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.ChildMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        this.ViewAccess = new List<Responsibility>();

    }
}
}
```

CATEGORY SECUIRTY - DOESNT WORK

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Workflow.Data.Template;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Workflow.Data.Access
{
/// <summary>
/// Defines a Security object specific to a Category
/// </summary>
public class CategorySecurity : Security
{
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    //[InverseProperty("Permissions")]
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public CategorySecurity() : base() { }
}
}
```

SECURITY - the parent:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Workflow.Data.Enum;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Workflow.Data.Access
{
/// <summary>
/// Defines a Security in the workflow, which will have a type to define the level of access and a List or Responsibility objects that have that access.
/// </summary>
[Table("Security", Schema = "wfa")]
public class Security
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TypeID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Type")]
    public SecurityType Type { 
        get
        {
            return (SecurityType)TypeID;
        }

        set
        {
            TypeID = (int)value;
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Responsibilities")]
    [InverseProperty("Security")]
    public virtual ICollection<Responsibility> Responsibilities { get; set; }

    public Security()
    {
        this.Responsibilities = new List<Responsibility>();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you expect a proxy but don't get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was surrounding the "rules" required for a POCO class to be created into a DynamicProxy. I had several things that were wrong; for instance I did not have empty get;set; and I had several sets marked as internal.

Changes I made:

- Put the [NotMapped] attribute on gets and sets that were not empty.
- Ensured:

  - class was public
  - all collections were ICollection
  - all gets and sets were public
  - im also lazy loading all Collections, but I dont think that should make a difference

Here is a good article that helped me: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/

Cheers!